# How to add veracode scanning to JFrog artifactory

Tags: artifactory, veracode

Hi I am trying to find a simple solution to run a static security scan on binaries stored in JFrog Artifactory. It looks like the veracode integration supports Artifactory 6.7.8 (https://community.veracode.com/s/article/Support-Matrix). Has anyone used this plugin with newer versions of Artifactory? If so how did you add the plugin to Artifactory? I'm trying to find a simple way to add the integration.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by using `rtUpload` and `rtDownload` jenkins plugins. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax.

1. Make a repo for the binaries
2. Write a function for uploading the binaries to artifactory
3. Write a function for downloading the binaries from artifactroy